# GWT DateTimeFormat returns the wrong date

Tags: date, gwt, datetime

I have the following code

```
        String test = "21/04/2013";
        fmt = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        Date dateTest = fmt.parse(test);
        Window.alert(fmt.format(dateTest));
```

And the alert box shows the date

```
  09/04/2014
```

instead of

```
  21/04/2013
```

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others already say, it's because of your pattern. What they don't say is **why** it behaves that way.

When parsing `21/04/2013` as `MM/dd/yyyy`, `DateTimeFormat` will decompose the date as:

```
Month  Day of month  Year
  21        4        2013
```

and it'll then adjust things to make a valid date. To do that, the **Month** part is truncated at `12` (so that temporary date is **Dec 4th, 2013**) and the remainder (*21 - 12 = 9*) is then added, leading to **Sept. 4th 2014**, which according to your format displays as `09/04/2014`.

Comment: hmm. I would from far prefer it to throw an explicit exception here and to use a roll method for this kind of operation. It would have avoided such a question

Comment: That was really embarrassing. Thanks everyone for your answers, I +1'ed them all. Yes, an exception would have saved me the question :)

Comment: Is there any way to escape this behaviour?

Comment: Try using `parseStrict` instead of `parse`?

Answer (score 2):

You wanted to show `21/04/2013` but the format was `MM/dd/yyyy`.
It should be `dd/MM/yyyy`

So change it like this:

```
String test = "21/04/2013";
fmt = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date dateTest = fmt.parse(test);
Window.alert(fmt.format(dateTest));
```

Answer (score 2):

You're reversing day and month.

```
String test = "21/04/2013";
fmt = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date dateTest = fmt.parse(test);
Window.alert(fmt.format(dateTest));
```